# How I can use SD card as internal memory?

Tags: applications, samsung, insufficient-memory, adoptable-storage

I am using **Samsung Galaxy Prime+ - SM-G532F** device running Android 6.0.1. The problem I am facing is that. My device has very low internal memory, whenever I try to install more then 3 normal application an **error** encounters that please delete previous application to install other application.

So, I tried to find ways to use SD Card as app installation memory but problem is same there is not any option available in this device to migrate applications from internal storage to SD Card.

Please someone help me on this irritating problem

Comment: In that case, mentioned [adoptable-storage tag-wiki](/tags/adoptable-storage/info) is the perfect starting-point. Be aware not only of the "pros" of that, but also of the drawbacks before you enable adaptable storage. In your case, advantages might outweight the drawbacks, though.

Answer (score 1):

If you buy a brand new Sdcard which you did not use or plug into another device, and insert it into your phone, you should get a notification that says something like this : "Use Sdcard as internal storage" . You can click that notification and accept it. It should now treat your Sdcard as as internal storage. Make sure that you do not remove that Sdcard after that.

Check this website for more information :
https://www.nextpit.com/how-to-format-microsd-cards-as-internal-storage

Answer (score 0):

First backup whatever you find valuable in your SD card. Next remove your SD card after power off. Insert it back and reboot. After in your status bar you will see option to set up sd card. Select use as internal. The reset process should start and viola. NB. YOU WON'T BE ABLE TO USE YOUR SD CARD WITH OTHER PHONES WITHOUT FORMATTING

Answer (score 0):

Most of OEM's doesn't offer in gui option for adoptable storage. So you have to do it via ADB. [Here](http://www.modaco.com/news/android/heres-how-to-configure-adoptable-storage-on-your-s7-s7-edge-r1632/) is how

Here it is:
NOTE  all data on your SD card will be lost.

1. Make sure USB debugging is enabled in developer options under settings and then connect your phone to PC via USB cable.
2. Open terminal or command line on PC ( make sure you have ADB installed if not then download minimal ADB and fastboot, you can find it on Google [click](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2317790) ) type command "**adb devices**" to make sure phone is detected, then type "**adb shell**"
   3.Type '**sm list-disks**' to list the disks available, the result should be something like "*disk:179:160*"
3. To make SD adoptable use command "**sm partition disk:xxx:xxx private**" where *xxx:xxx* is replaced with result from previous command, in some cases there is **_** instead of **:** so watch out for that. If you want to use only half of SD as adoptable then use this command "**sm partition disk:xxx:xxx mixed 50**" and that's it.

If you want to move your data (pictures, videos etc) you can go to settings>storage>SD card>more and you will have there option "migrate data" hit it and let it go.